# How to change dictionary elements in words?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

i want to change this dictionary

```
d = {"p ": {"e ": {"l ": {"t ": {}},
                   "t ": {}},
            "o ": {"t ": {}}},
     "t ": {"i ": {"a ": {},
                   "m ": {}},
            "e ": {"o ": {}}}}
```

to list of words [’pet’, ’pelt’, ’pot’, ’tim’, ’tia’, ’teo’] and i do not know how to do it.

Comment: It's very unclear how you get your output list of words from the dictionary. Can you explain the logic you want to apply?

Comment: for example "p " -> "e " -> "l " -> "t " -> {} gives us "pelt"
                    "p " -> "e " ->"t " -> {} gives us "pet" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recursion! Also generators make it nice.

```
def paths(tree):
    if not tree:
        yield ''
    for k, subtree in tree.items():
        for path in paths(subtree):
            yield k + path

print(list(paths(d)))
```

Comment: I'm surprised how effective this actually was. still trying to wrap my brain around how recursion works :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
final_words = [[[key+i+e+''.join(l[e].keys()) if l[e] else key+i+e for e in l] for i, l in vals.items()] for key, vals in d.items()]
final_data = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in final_words]))
new_final_data = [''.join(i.split()) for i in final_data]
```

Output:

```
['pet', 'pelt', 'pot', 'tia', 'tim', 'teo']
```